# loop counter set to itself in a nested for loop, what does that mean?

Tags: c++

For a project I am working on, I need to go through source code from a C++ program.

At several locations I am seeing something that I don't understand and I can't find anything about on the internet.

In several nested for loops, the counter var for the outer loop is set to itself. Is that to exit the loop, to skip one, anybody have any idea?

So it's the "n = n;" part :)

```
for (int n = 0; n < 12; n++) {
    for (int m = 0; m < 99; m++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < 10000; p++) {
            if (p == 2300) {
                n = n;
            }
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like someone wanted a line of code they could put a breakpoint on when debugging to catch it when `p` is equal to 2300.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Although you may be right, but there are tons of possible no-use lines of code that someone could write which are less confusing than this one..

Comment: Code makes little sense as is. Is it possible that in paraphrasing the code you changed something key to it's operation? Maybe copying and pasting the actual code might clarify.

Comment: I would like to add that VS (on Windows) has nice debugging features which makes such codes rather obsolete. However, I would always enclose code dedicated for debugging into something like `#ifdef _DEBUG` and `#endif // _DEBUG` (what deactivates it in release builds and provides the human intention for free).

Comment: @Scheff Those debugging features (e.g. conditional breakpoints) can be unbearably slow. I've had cases where it's faster to add code similar to the one in question, rebuild and run again than waiting for some tight loop to finally satisfy my debug condition.

Comment: Though, thinking twice `if (p == 2300) { n = n; }` might be optimized out in release builds (with optimization enabled). (May be, it's not that stupid that I thought at first glance.) Checked that on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/NCsStk) with gcc.

Comment: @ChrisDrew You may be right. In debug the if statement would  not be compiled away  but in release it should because of the n=n statement. So possibly a cryptic way to have a line to set a  breakpoint with no release build consequences. Thing is if you know that, surely you know how to set a conditional breakpoint in the debugger? The mind boggles.@Max Langhof just read your comment about slow conditional breakpoints, not experienced it myself but good to know.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I agree that debugging in VS can slow down certain things significantly. But I'm still convinced that a comment or an `#ifdef _DEBUG` is valuable always (for the not so clever readers like me).

Comment: this is the code as it was written by someone else, I have left out the actual code for privacy reasons, but it's just about that " n=n; " bit, I couldn't work out what it meant, but it looks like it doesn't do anything. I had the idea he wanted to shorten the inner loop, but then why wouldn't he just have done " p < 2300 " then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `n = n;` line of code does not do anything and the whole `if (p == 2300) { n = n; }` part will probably be optimized away in a release build.

I suspect the reason the original author did this was so that they could put a breakpoint on the `n = n;` line and catch it in the debugger when p is 2300. They probably submitted the change by mistake.

Modern IDEs will typically have a way of setting conditional breakpoints to break on such conditions but they can be slow and sometimes it is faster to recompile with a condition like this in.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's _the answer_ but it's probably the most reasonable answer for such code. ;-)

Comment: I'd add that this isn't a good way to do conditional breakpoints as it's cryptic at best . A better way would have been to have an if statement in a  #if_def _DEBUG to make it more obvious.

Comment: @Rich: those debug code should not be submitted at first.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right, the code should never have been allowed to stay in.